# New way to add object in array

Tags: ios, objective-c

How you add new object in an array, using new Objective-C syntax.

I know it is `addObject:`, `addObjectAtIndex:` etc but i was asked to do it in new way.

What is new way?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no "new" way to "insert" an object at an index location in an NSArray.  There is the "new" `[]` notation to replace an object or add one at the end of the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *mArray = [NSMutableArray new];
mArray[mArray.count] = @"newvalue"; // this can be any object
```

Above is equivalent to `addObject:`.

[This is must read for you](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html).

Comment: There is no `addObject:atIndex:` method, you mean `insertObject:atIndex:`, but that is not equivalent to `mArray[index]=object`, but rather to `replaceObject:atIndex:`.

Comment: Now I am thinking what is the new way to `insertObj:atIndex:` :D